# Where did Martin Luther say that he placed "his Christ higher than any dogma or council"?

Tags: reference-request, martin-luther

In which of his writings did Luther say something like "I am not trying to be arrogant here, but I place my Christ higher than any dogma or council"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Luther wrote extensively, and in German, making quote identification rather difficult.  However, the language you use here is reminiscent of Luther's famous speech at the [Diet of Worms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diet_of_Worms), where he said:

> Unless I am convinced by the testimony of the Scriptures or by clear reason (for I do not trust either in the pope or in councils alone, since it is well known that they have often erred and contradicted themselves), I am bound by the Scriptures I have quoted and my conscience is captive to the Word of God. I cannot and will not recant anything, since it is neither safe nor right to go against conscience. May God help me. Amen. ([Marty, *Martin Luther*, 68](https://books.google.com/books?id=2-EOdMOEtPoC&pg=PA68))

Here, however, Luther does not say that *Christ* is higher than the councils, but rather the Scriptures.  He does connect the two in other writings, and perhaps come closer to your language:

> I pray the God of all mercies that he teach Your Grace this one thing, that Christ and his Word are more, higher, greater, and more trustworthy than a hundred thousand holy fathers, councils, churches, popes, etc., for the Scriptures call all of these sinners and lost sheep. ([*Luther: Letters*, 164](https://books.google.com/books?id=XdIX8_EMTbQC&pg=PA164))